# How to unpack a single file

Tags: electron-packager

This is my structure:

```
MyApp
|--node_modules
|--config.json
```

I can create an asar running this command "C:\Users\murilo\Desktop>asar pack MyApp app.asar --unpack config.json" but I can't usigng electron-package.. I tried everything I see and nothing works:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack='config.json' --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack='MyApp/config.json' --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack='**/config.json' --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack={config.json} --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack='*.json' --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --asar.unpack='./config.json' --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

and a lot else!!!!

How can I make it works???

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but maybe this helps you or anybody else:

Since --asar override any other --asar* argument ([see test case](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/test/cli.js#L26-L32)) your call cannot work at all.

This should work for copying all files with extension .json:

```
electron-packager . --overwrite --asar.unpack=\"{*.json}\" --platform=win32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

When you want to see in your console whats going on set `DEBUG=electron-packager` e.g. like this

```
cross-env DEBUG=electron-packager electron-packager ......
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: to clarify --asar and --asar.unpack can not be used together. Use only --asar.unpack for the unpacking files